# Reading one line from a Unix domain socket

Tags: perl, sockets, unix-socket, perl-io

I have a server running `socat` with this command:

```
socat ABSTRACT-LISTEN:test123 PIPE
```

I can open a socket to this server, send one line, read one line, and print it with this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::Socket::UNIX;

my $sock = IO::Socket::UNIX->new(
    Type => SOCK_STREAM(),
    Peer => "\0test123"
) or die "Error creating socket: $!\n";

print $sock "Hello, world!\n";
my $line = <$sock>;
close $sock;

print $line;
```

When I replace the last 5 lines with the following, however, the program hangs:

```
print <$sock>;
```

Isn't the `<FILEHANDLE>` operator supposed to read one line from the handle? Why can I not read one line and print it?

Comment: Out of curiosity: What is the purpose of the null character in the beginning of the `Peer` name?

Comment: @HåkonHægland On Linux, the null character creates an abstract Unix socket. This is a socket that exists outside of the filesystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print <$sock>` is imposing list context to [readline](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html) and thus reads and returns all lines until the end-of-file.

As noted in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators) :

> If a  is used in a context that is looking for a list, a list comprising all input lines is returned, one line per list element.

As noted by Hakon-Haegland in his comment below, a concise way to read only one line is to impose scalar context:

```
print scalar <$sock>
```

Comment: OK, thanks. How would I instruct it to only get one line?

Comment: To read from `$sock` in scalar context: `print scalar <$sock>`. This will read a single line